# Adding a ramp to a switch

Tags: voltage, switches

I have a SPDT switch that switches between a signal voltage of -5 to +5v and ground.

The signal is a mix of slow(ish) moving waves (sine, triangle, envelopes) and audio (both -5 to +5v)

When switching from the signal voltage to ground I don't want an abrupt change as this will cause an unsavoury pop for audio.

Can someone give me a pointer to solve this?

James

Comment: Normally we specify poles first, then throws.

Comment: Maybe a capacitor somewhere to prevent fast voltage transients?

Answer (score 2):

There are parts out there made for this like [this one](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NLAS6233-D.PDF).

It takes a digital input, but you can just connect your switch to that with a pull up resistor (can use SPST now).

Answer (score 0):

You need something more complex than just a switch to avoid abrupt changes in the signal when changing the signal level.

You probably need to smoothly attenuate the signal over a short period maybe using a digipot (controllable attenuator).

Even then you can generate zipper noise. This is a link to a design that avoids this by only changing the level at zero crossings.[Eliminate zipper noise](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/digital-volume-control-eliminates-zipper-noise)

Alternatively you could use an analog attenuator fed with a ramp to enable or disable.

You can use MOSFETS or even diodes.

One way is a shunt diode based attenuator - the current through the diode will control how much attenuation is given to the signal.  This type of attenuator is only good for a few tens of millivolts of signal or distortion will occur so you will need to lower the input level and amplify it at the output. The 100uF capacitor and resistor network causes the control signal to ramp up and down with the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQEeuo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>